# Basics of argument passing in R's functions

Tags: r, functional-programming, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

How R interpret line : `arg.list <- list(x, y)` in below definition of function, does it copy `x` and `y` into `arg.list` object when execution happen or they are passed by reference ?

```
fplot <- function(x, y, add=FALSE){
  arg.list <- list(x, y)
  if(!add){
    plot(arg.list))
  }else{
    lines(arg.list)
  }
}
```

Comment: Please note that your current question has nothing to do with argument passing into functions (as the title implies) but constructing container variables from scalar vector variables... Was this really your intention?

Comment: @R Yoda, in my real function, `x` and `y` are `data.frame`, then I use them like: `x$var1`

Comment: x and y are definitely copied if you modify it outside or inside of the function (until then "copy on first modification" is still true to avoid unnecessary memory copies). `x$var` yields a vector...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variables are embedded into the list by reference (at least if you use vectors).

Proof:

```
library(pryr)

x <-   1:100
y <- 201:200

arg.list <- list(x,y)

al.x <- arg.list[[1]]
al.y <- arg.list[[2]]
```

Now look at the memory addresses (they are the same):

```
> address(x)
[1] "0x37598c0"
> address(y)
[1] "0x40fd6f8"
> address(al.x)
[1] "0x37598c0"
> address(al.y)
[1] "0x40fd6f8"
```

If you change one item a copy will be created ("copy on modification"):

```
> x[1]=42
> address(x)
[1] "0x417a470"
> al.x <- arg.list[[1]]
> address(al.x)
[1] "0x37598c0"
```

**Edit:**

As @HongOoi said: R semantically never uses references (except for objects in the environment class) but copies for variables. It "is clever enough to avoid copies until they are really required" ("copy on [first] modification"). Function parameters are passed "by value" semantically (even though references are used until a modification occurs).

Answer (score 3):

The *semantics* of R is that function arguments are always passed *by value*. The underlying implementation may not necessarily make new copies of the arguments, so as to save memory. But your function will behave as if it has brand-new copies to work with.

This means you don't have to worry about changing a variable outside a function because you changed it inside:

```
x <- 1
f <- function(z) {
    z <- z + 1
    z
}

y <- f(x)
print(y)  # y now contains 2
print(x)  # but x still contains 1
```

If R was pass-by-reference, then modifying the argument of `f` would also modify the variable that was passed in. This doesn't happen.

Comment: so what about R Yoda answer ?

Comment: Yoda's answer is about the internals of R. It's smart enough not to make a copy of an argument unless it's needed. For example, if my function `f` didn't modify its argument at all: `f <- function(z) { return(z + 1) }` then it wouldn't bother making a new copy of `z`. However, the outward behaviour of `f` is always _as if_ a new copy of the argument was made.

Comment: There are some areas where R is pass-by-reference, namely environments. I might add that to the answer later.

Comment: I understand, but what about my example, where, there is no modification, but only composition ? @R Yoda says its holds for vectors, is it true for another objects ?

Comment: The current wording of the question is ambigious. Does the OP want to know how function parameters are passed (as the title implies) or whether object composition is done by ref or by value? @Qbik Please clarify this. HongOoi's Your answer is more appropriate I have to admit because it explains the internals better :-)

Comment: @R Yoda, yours  better suits me because it show how to test it for myself and I previously new about '"copy on [first] modification"